# Ooyala HTML5 / Javascript API - Play video in fullscreen

Tags: android, ios, html, ooyala

I want to make all the videos play full screen in android/ios. i am using the ooyala player for playback.

```
<div class="sResult" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(2).playMovie();" style="display: block; ">...</div>
```

When I trigger the .playMovie() function I want to play the movie in fullscreen. Is there any function call or parameter i can use to do so?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to programmatically control the fullscreen functionality of the Ooyala Player.

On Android, the Ooyala Player will automatically go to fullscreen when played on a phone.  Tablets will still be played inline, and it is not yet possible to control fullscreen on the Flash Player from javascript, as Flash throws security errors.

For HTML5/iOS, you can call fullscreen on the underlying video tag-
In your case, that would be something like: "if(document.getElementById(2).getElementsByTagName('video')[0]) document.getElementById(2).getElementsByTagName('video')[0].webkitRequestFullScreen();"